# why my program is not ran by qemu is it because its for emulating only Linux -- On Linux

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, qemu

I am trying to run my binary for virtual board of ARM versatilepb board in Qemu. I used the command to run it like this

```
  qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin

test.bin is my program. a really a simple program that writes to tty. but it gives me error that 

ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `lm4549.out'
```

the above output is just to tell that some drivers are not found in my program. But thats for linux, and assuming Qemu is to emulate linux but my program is ain't linux its barely a program. just simple writing to tty. So is there any way I can force my program to run successfully on Qemu even after given that sole purpose of Qemu is to run linux based systems and boards. Can I get lucky and able to run it in Qemu

This is simple C file

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;

void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
 *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}

void c_entry() {
 print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

ld script

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

and asm file so called simply for booting kernel

```
.section INTERRUPT_VECTOR, "x"
.global _Reset
_Reset:
  B Reset_Handler /* Reset */
  B . /* Undefined */
  B . /* SWI */
  B . /* Prefetch Abort */
  B . /* Data Abort */
  B . /* reserved */
  B . /* IRQ */
  B . /* FIQ */
 
Reset_Handler:
  LDR sp, =stack_top
  BL c_entry
  B .
```

Or is there any other option I have? may this and for debugging programs?

Comment: I need Linux based hypervisor thing that I can use on to run my program on my system

Answer (score 0):

The warnings output there are not related to the fact that your binary produces no output. They are from your host system's ALSA library, and they happen because:

- the versatilepb board has an audio device
- you don't seem to have a valid ALSA configuration set up on your host
- QEMU is defaulting to trying ALSA for sound output

You can either:

- ignore the warnings
- configure ALSA on your host machine
- tell QEMU to use a different audio backend by setting the QEMU_AUDIO_DRV environment variable (eg you can set it to "none" to say "throw away audio output from the guest")

The lack of output from your guest binary is probably a bug or misconfiguration either in the guest program itself, in how you are building it (where you're linking it, etc), or in how you're telling QEMU to load it. Your best bet for debugging this is to use QEMU's builtin gdbstub, and connect an Arm-aware gdb to it. Then you can single-step through what happens one instruction at a time.

Another point to note: QEMU's "-kernel" option means (if you don't pass it an ELF file) "this is a Linux kernel, please start it in the way that Linux kernels want to be started". It looks from your provision of a reset handler that what you want is "load this file into the machine and start the CPU out of reset as the hardware would normally reset". To do that you should use the 
[generic loader](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/generic-loader.html) device.

Comment: `tell QEMU to use a different audio backend by setting the QEMU_AUDIO_DRV environment variable (eg you can set it to "none" to say "throw away audio output from the guest")` and how should I do this. do I need to specify in any file

Comment: also please let me know how to ignore `ignore the warnings`